# Is it possible to customize Cordova InAppBrowser (I need to add custom buttons, bars etc.)

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I have several questions and still didn't find an answer for them. I need to build such type of interface  using Cordova InAppBrowser: https://gyazo.com/fcc1ae22859a7196e1a8f6d0ef4a9f93

So my questions are:

1) Is it possible to hide search field? because I need to open only my links and don't want to open some other links

2) Is it possible to add custom buttons to the top toolbar?

3) Is it possible to add custom buttons to the bottom toolbar?

4) Is it possible hide or customize “back” and “forward” buttons?

5) Is it possible to change color of top and bottom toolbars?

6) Is it possible to open a pop-up window over browser like this https://gyazo.com/80e60421e3eaa854f7bb953c274f12c2 when I enter any of my custom button from this screen https://gyazo.com/fcc1ae22859a7196e1a8f6d0ef4a9f93?

7) Is it possible to add additional bar under the bottom bar like this: https://gyazo.com/f7802b78ce3215d8d65b6ccc689cdd31 ?

Thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Is it possible to hide search field? because I need to open only my
>   links and don't want to open some other links

Yes.  var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');

> 2) Is it possible to add custom buttons to the top toolbar?

No.  This should be done in your web app.

> 3) Is it possible to add custom buttons to the bottom toolbar?

No.  This should be done in your web app.

> 4) Is it possible hide or customize “back” and “forward” buttons?

You can hide.  But not customize.  See answer to number 2.

> 5) Is it possible to change color of top and bottom toolbars?

again this should be in your web app, and not modifying the plugin.

> 6) Is it possible to open a pop-up window over browser like this
>   https://gyazo.com/80e60421e3eaa854f7bb953c274f12c2 when I enter any of
>   my custom button from this screen
>   https://gyazo.com/fcc1ae22859a7196e1a8f6d0ef4a9f93?

You really need to read the docs for the InappBrowser

> 7) Is it possible to add additional bar under the bottom bar like
>   this: https://gyazo.com/f7802b78ce3215d8d65b6ccc689cdd31 ?

Again, this should be done in your web app, not the plugin.